# Cant start service inside inner class broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-service

I'm trying to start a service from a button in notification. I use same button to start and stop. The stop works but when I start again I see in the debugger the code executes the startService part but doesn't start the service, doesn't show an exception either. Please help.

```
   public static class switchButtonListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (startStopCount == 0) {
            new OuterClassService().timer.cancel();
            new OuterClassService.ScreenshotService().stopSelf();
            startStopCount = 1;
        } else {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, OuterClassService.ScreenshotService.class));
            startStopCount = 0;
        }
    }
```

The first time notification but is pressed, it works and the service stops, but when I use the same button to start again, it doesn't start the service

Comment: Post the button code, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no code in here that either starts or stops a service. If `OuterClassService.ScreenshotService()` is a `Service`, you cannot create an instance of that class yourself and expect it to work.

To start a service, call `startService()` on a `Context`, passing in an `Intent` that identifies the service.

To stop a service from outside the service, call `stopService()` on a `Context`, passing in an `Intent` that identifies the service. To stop a service from inside **a running instance of the service**, call `stopSelf()`.

Comment: i'm sorry..you're right. i probably just stopped the `Timer` and thought the `Service` stopped.